# Decompress gzipped http request

Tags: android, fiddler

I'm trying to decompress an **HTTP POST** request originating from my Android handset.  I've set up a proxy using Fiddler to capture the requests but am having a hard time trying to decompress the captured data.  I'm using an windows laptop to run **Fiddler** to capture the requests over WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler will automatically decode gzip all responses if you toggle the toolbar button "Decode". Otherwise you can do it manually for a response by clicking the yellow bar above the response view. It says "Response body is encoded, click to decode".

[image]

Comment: it's possible to do this decoding using Java code ?